# Transpose hourly data in rows to new columns Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, transpose

I have a table recorded hourly weather data like this:

[image]

```
                        Year Month  Day Time   Temp     
    Date/Time                                                   
    2005-01-01 00:00:00 2005    1   1   0:00    6.0 
    2005-01-01 01:00:00 2005    1   1   1:00    6.1 
    2005-01-01 02:00:00 2005    1   1   2:00    6.7 
    2005-01-01 03:00:00 2005    1   1   3:00    6.8 
    2005-01-01 04:00:00 2005    1   1   4:00    6.3 
    2005-01-01 05:00:00 2005    1   1   5:00    6.6 
    2005-01-01 06:00:00 2005    1   1   6:00    6.9 
    2005-01-01 07:00:00 2005    1   1   7:00    7.1 
    2005-01-01 08:00:00 2005    1   1   8:00    6.9 
    2005-01-01 09:00:00 2005    1   1   9:00    6.7 
    2005-01-01 10:00:00 2005    1   1   10:00   7.1 
    2005-01-01 11:00:00 2005    1   1   11:00   7.1 
    2005-01-01 12:00:00 2005    1   1   12:00   7.2 
    2005-01-01 13:00:00 2005    1   1   13:00   7.7 
    2005-01-01 14:00:00 2005    1   1   14:00   8.8 
    2005-01-01 15:00:00 2005    1   1   15:00   8.6 
    2005-01-01 16:00:00 2005    1   1   16:00   7.4 
    2005-01-01 17:00:00 2005    1   1   17:00   6.8 
    2005-01-01 18:00:00 2005    1   1   18:00   6.3 
    2005-01-01 19:00:00 2005    1   1   19:00   5.9 
    2005-01-01 20:00:00 2005    1   1   20:00   5.6 
    2005-01-01 21:00:00 2005    1   1   21:00   3.6 
    2005-01-01 22:00:00 2005    1   1   22:00   2.6 
    2005-01-01 23:00:00 2005    1   1   23:00   1.7
```

I wanted to save the dataframe in this format:

[image]

How can I transpose the dataframe and create new columns for each record?

Comment: Can you copy and paste data into SO instead of an image?

Comment: @DavidErickson Edit now.

Comment: okay your data was copy/pasting weird with pd.read_clipboard() because it looks like you have a multi index or something (column headers not on same row).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Copy below data

```
        Date/Time       Year    Month   Day  Time   Temp
0       1/1/2005 0:00   2005    1       1   0:00    6.0
1       1/1/2005 1:00   2005    1       1   1:00    6.1
2       1/1/2005 2:00   2005    1       1   2:00    6.7
3       1/1/2005 3:00   2005    1       1   3:00    6.8
4       1/1/2005 4:00   2005    1       1   4:00    6.3
5       1/1/2005 5:00   2005    1       1   5:00    6.6
6       1/1/2005 6:00   2005    1       1   6:00    6.9
7       1/1/2005 7:00   2005    1       1   7:00    7.1
8       1/1/2005 8:00   2005    1       1   8:00    6.9
9       1/1/2005 9:00   2005    1       1   9:00    6.7
10      1/1/2005 10:00  2005    1       1   10:00   7.1
11      1/1/2005 11:00  2005    1       1   11:00   7.1
12      1/1/2005 12:00  2005    1       1   12:00   7.2
```

2) Use pd.read_clipboard with a **double space or more** param due to space in Date/Time column

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_clipboard('\s\s+')
df
```

3) format date/time columns and create a pivot table and reset/rename axis.

```
df['Date/Time']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time'],format='%m/%d/%Y 
%H:%M').dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
df['Time']=pd.to_datetime(df['Time']).dt.time
df=pd.pivot_table(df, index='Date/Time', columns='Time', values='Temp').reset_index().rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
df['Date/Time']=df['Date/Time'].apply(lambda x:(x + ' 0:00'))
df
```

Output:

```
Date/Time  00:00:00  01:00:00  02:00:00  03:00:00  04:00:00  05:00:00  06:00:00  07:00:00  08:00:00  09:00:00  10:00:00  11:00:00  12:00:00
01/01/2005      6.0      6.1      6.7      6.8          6.3      6.6        6.9  7.1       6.9         6.7         7.1        7.1       7.2
```

Comment: I would like to have 1 row contains all hourly data in columns, not a pivot table having 24x24 for the date of the specific day.

Comment: the ouput is giving me a 1x24 like in the edited answer, where I have added Output... doesn't look like that for you?

Comment: Yes, it is give me a 1x24 now. I somehow got a pivot table like result previously.

Comment: no problem @Meruemu I added one line of code at the end, so you can have in exact format.

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick similarly to previous answer but on a new date column such that only one row per day is created:

```
datetimes = pd.date_range("2005-01-01 00:00:00","2005-01-02 23:00:00", freq="1h")
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date/Time": datetimes, "temp": rand(len(datetimes))})
df["Date"] = df["Date/Time"].dt.date
df["Hour"] = df["Date/Time"].dt.hour
reshaped= df.pivot(index='Date', columns='Hour', values='temp')
reshaped.columns = ['HR'+str(hour) for hour in reshaped.columns]
```

Comment: my answer also only has one row per day when I run it. That's because I edited DateTime format to date, I'm not sure if that is a require for the OP to have it as Date Time. I guess it would also make sense to rename that column or create a new column called "Date".

Comment: You're right. Previously assumed it created 24x24 dataframe based on comment by OP.